# UIScrollView content visible then bounces away

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiscrollview

I have a pretty simple UIScrollView defined inside Interface Builder. I've pasted in some UILabels and when I run my app, I can drag to see the UILabels at the bottom but as soon as I let go it bounces away from view.

What property controls this sort of setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contentSize` property should do the trick. Don't forget about the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Comment: Yeah I have that. It seems to be ignoring the values I set. I know my scroll view outlet is correctly hooked up but whether I do  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000) or (320,10) it doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

For the bounce effect there is a `bounces` property for `UIScrollView` which controls this...

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/bounces

And has been mentioned by Ian Henry `contentSize` should control the size of your scrollable area.

Comment: Yeah I'm working with those. The bouncing is fine (I like it), but it's like when I hold the scroll I can see the last few lines, when I let go, it bounces out of visibility. Ideally it would still be visible.

Comment: Scratch that. I got it fixed. I was manipulating the wrong scrollview. Thanks.

Comment: Great glad you got thinks fixed.